# PHP equivalent to C# string.IsNullOrEmpty method?

Tags: c#, php, string, null

is there an official equivalent to the C# isNullOrEmpty method in PHP? I know there is empty and such, but is this the same?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm using `strlen` for checking if string is null or empty.

```
if (strlen($str) == 0){
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: How about adding a trim just before the $str ? Would that help make empty spaces ? Like `if (strlen(trim($str)) == 0) { `

Comment: This answer must be correct perse because it´s by Chuck Norris (-:

Comment: As of PHP 8.1 "Deprecated: strlen(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated"

Answer (score 12):

The [empty()](http://php.net/empty) method also considers NULL as an empty value. As well as all these values:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

Comment: Thanks, this wont work in my case because values such as 0 are not considered as empty in my code.

Comment: @EOB Yeah, sometimes that's the pain with the empty() method. Then you should use something like `if(is_null($var) || $var == "")`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check string empty but not in case of 0 then try this..

```
if (!is_numeric($str) && empty($str))
```

here `is_numeric` check for string is not a number value, and then `empty` check for null.

thanks..